# Vue 3 handling script tag inside root element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to avoid Vue from compiling script tag inside root element. Here is a code example:

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script>const app = Vue.createApp({});</script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="global_component_bundled.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="myJsFile.js"></script>
    <global-component></global-component>
  </div>
  <script>app.mount("#app");</script>
</body>
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```html
<script>app.config.isCustomElement = tag => tag.startsWith('script');</script>
```

but that doesn't work unfortunately for script tag.

The Problem is the warnings what i'm getting on browser console. Maybe is there any way to disable the warnings for script tag or to disable Vue from compiling this tag?

I know that i can do something like this:

```html
<script>app.config.warnHandler = () => null;</script>
```

But i just want to disable this warning if is not possible vue to ignore compiling script tag:

> Template compilation error: Tags with side effect (script and style) are ignored in client component templates.

But i prefer a way to ignore the script tag instead of disabling the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get rid of the warning by using `type="application/javascript"` in all of the `<script>` tags.

Comment: that's work on Vue 2 but my question was about Vue 3 and if you look at my Code you can see that i'm already using `type="application/javascript"`